# When reating an animation do you create all assets in one blend file?

Tags: animation

Noob question.

Ive modelled my first car and Im about to model a road followed by road furniture etc

Should I model them in all in the same file or several and then bring them together?

Comment: The choice is up to you. Sometimes it's nicer to work on a single object at a time, other times it's nice to have the other objects in the same scene to help provide a sense of scale. Also, you could make a separate collection for each object, and hide/reveal them as needed. Heck, with blender, you could even have 2 blender windows open at once and copy+paste from one to the other. Sky's the limit.

Comment: Hey :). It's often useful to link finished assets into a separate Blendfile for animating/rendering. Since they're all links, such file is very lightweight (1-2mb) and fast to work with.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Creating separate *Scenes* inside a blendfile is also a great way to organize assets :).